# unused post IDs

Tags: posts, id

Recently I installed plugin called Delete-Revision and noticed that every post has registered few post IDs. I usually use save drafts and update post a few times when I write a post. Here's the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pqgx.png . As you see I have 53 posts and Wordpress already registered 646 post IDs. How can I stop it and clear unused IDs?

Comment: It's unclear what delete-revision has done/is supposed to do?

Comment: It's not about revisions. I want Wordpress to stop making new IDs on the same post everytime I press save draft or update buttons.

Comment: You can't stop WordPress doing that. This is how WordPress works. How else can it distinguish between versions of a post?

Comment: then how can I prevent Wordpress from creating versions of a post(to have only original one) and remove the unused ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stop WP creating revisions by adding the following to your wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );
```

You can replace `false` with an integer if you just want to restrict the number a maximum number of revisions.

If you check the [plugin directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) you'll find several that will clean up old revisions, such as [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-clean-up/).

You cannot turn off drafts. You can reduce the frequency of autosaves if you wish, but WP only keeps one autosave per post anyway:

```
define('AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 160 );  // seconds
```